# mongodb: Is there a way to print the related field value when error occurs in aggregation?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, mongodb, pymongo

Say I have a collection, in which the documents look like this:

```
{
  pattern: ABC
},
{
  pattern: QWE
}
```

The field "pattern" is just a pattern that can be used in regex.

Now I would like to find all documents of which the pattern can be matched to a text.

Say the text looks like this: `ABCEFD`

I want to get all documents of which the pattern got matched to the text. So in this case the document  `{ pattern: ABC }` is returned.

Now I have a bunch of this pattern documents and I have a very long text. I executed the following code

```
    coll_patterns.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": 
            {
                "$expr": {
                    "$regexMatch": {
                    "input": text,
                    "regex": "$pattern"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { "$out" : coll_matched}
    ])
```

And got this error

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: 
PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Error occurred while executing the regular expression in $regexMatch. 
Result code: -21, full error: 
{'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Error occurred while executing the regular expression in $regexMatch. 
Result code: -21', 'code': 51156, 'codeName': 'Location51156'}
```

The error code and error message don't tell much. I would like to find out the cause, maybe to find which specific document causes this error.

How can I do this?
Or is the aggregation strategy and its query are not good for my use case? Is there any other way to achieve this "matching" task?

Comment: I don't know how many `"pattern"`s you have in the collection, but one option would be to "single-step" through each `"pattern"` to find the error.  Another strategy change might be to retrieve the patterns from the collection and do the pattern matching in Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot, pattern matching in Python works for me